# assignment from incompatible pointer type (C)

Tags: c

I code bellow, does rb_gst_get_encoding_profile does not return a gchar* as rec_settings.profile expects.

```
typedef struct Recording_Settings recording_settings;
struct Recording_Settings
{
    gchar *profile;
    gchar *destination;
};
recording_settings rec_settings;

typedef struct _GstEncodingProfile GstEncodingProfile;
GstEncodingProfile *rb_gst_get_encoding_profile (const char *media_type);
```

Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type:

```
rec_settings.profile = gconf_client_get_string(client, "/apps/sound/recording/profile", NULL);
if (!rec_settings.profile)
    rec_settings.profile = g_strdup("audio/x-vorbis");

static void profile_combo_change_cb(GtkComboBox *combo, gpointer userdata)
{
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    GtkTreeModel *model;

    /* Grab the encoding profile choosen */
    model = gtk_combo_box_get_model (GTK_COMBO_BOX (combo));
    if (gtk_combo_box_get_active_iter(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), &iter)) {
        gchar *media_type;
        gtk_tree_model_get(GTK_TREE_MODEL(model), &iter, 0, &media_type, -1);
        rec_settings.profile = rb_gst_get_encoding_profile(media_type); // Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
        g_free (media_type);
    }
}
```

I try to fix them. What is the way to do this?

Thanks

```
audio_profile_combo = audio_profile_chooser_new();
gchar *media_type;
media_type = rb_gst_encoding_profile_get_media_type(rec_settings.profile); // Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
audio_profile_chooser_set_active(audio_profile_combo, media_type);
g_free (media_type);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Recording_Settings struct to this:

```
struct Recording_Settings
{
    GstEncodingProfile *profile;
    gchar *destination;
};
```

At least, that's what I garner should be done from the little info available.

Comment: OK, but how call this: rec_settings.profile = gconf_client_get_string(client, "/apps/sound/recording/profile", NULL);
if (!rec_settings.profile)
    rec_settings.profile = g_strdup("audio/x-vorbis");

Comment: If you change the struct as above, then your code sample will work without change. The call get the profile will remain 'rec_settings.profile = rb_gst_get_encoding_profile(media_type); '

Comment: Still warning in function to save in gconf registry:                  gconf_client_set_string(client, "/apps/gnomeradio/recording/profile", rec_settings.profile, NULL); // passing argument 3 of 'gconf_client_set_string' from incompatible pointer type gconf-client.h:324:14: note: expected 'const gchar *' but argument is of type 'struct GstEncodingProfile *' Thanks

Comment: Your code sample above uses 'rb_gst_get_encoding_profile', but your comments are using 'gconf_client_set_string'. Which is it? Whatever it is, just make sure the function return type matches the variable type you are assigning it to.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
rec_settings.profile = rb_gst_get_encoding_profile(media_type);
```

`media_type` is a `gchar *`, but the function `rb_gst_get_encoding_profile` expects a `const char *`. That's the cause of the error.

**EDIT:** not to mention the function itself returns a `GstEncodingProfile *`, and you're trying to assign it to `rec_settings.profile`, which is a `gchar *`.